# Echo an input field with an echo POSTBACK value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, for-loop

So I'm iterating through a set value via a for loop, which will echo html input fields, every other echo'd html input field behaves as expected (including the name and id fields of the one below), however I keep getting syntax errors when trying to set the value as a postback to retain them on page submit.
Here is my code:

```
$type = "number".$i;
echo '<input type="text" name="'.$type.'" id="'.$type.'" value="'.<?php if (isset($_POST[$type])) { echo $_POST[$type]; } else { echo NULL;}.'" />';
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Reason: You're already inside PHP using `value="'.<?php if (isset($_POST[$type]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra `<?php` statement in the row. Since the line is `echo '...'.` you don't need to declare that more php code is coming. You can do something like this instead:

```
echo '<input type="text" name="'.$type.'" id="'.$type.'" value="';
if (isset($_POST[$type])) echo $_POST[$type];
echo '" />';
```

Although personally, I prefer to do something like `<input [...] id="{$type}" [...]"` outside of the php code, less messy.

Comment: Thanks mate, it's always the stupidly obvious things :P